# AppEnginePlatformError: URLFetch is not available in this environment. Local python Virtualenv

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, google-app-engine-python, urlfetch

I am not sure what I have done but from one day to the next all requests I am trying to run in my local environment lead to the same error:

```
"/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_toolbelt/adapters/appengine.py", line 122, in __init__
validate_certificate=validate_certificate)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/appengine.py", line 103, in __init__
"URLFetch is not available in this environment.")
AppEnginePlatformError: URLFetch is not available in this environment.
```

I am running a local virtualenv having basically followed the steps from here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages

I have tried searching for a solution but am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: You said that you were running this in a local environment, but "from one day to the next" it stopped working. Did you [activate the environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script)? 

Also, that example doesn't mention or uses URLFetch, as since it is an example of the Flexible Environment, and [you don't need to use URLFetch in Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#url_fetch). Did you edit this tutorial to try to use URLFetch?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah I did activate the environment. To be honest, I had/have no intention of using URLFetch. The error just seems  come from publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient() or a google places call (depending on what I call first). As far as I know the only thing that I changed since the code last worked was that mac os x updated.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I found my mistake and its frustratingly stupid. I was trying to test some FCM notifications and initialized with this line: `push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>", proxy_dict=proxy_dict, env='app_engine')` and was not at all aware that this would switch all requests to URLFetch

Comment: Hello, glad to see that it is solved. Could you post that last comment as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake: I was trying to test some FCM notifications using pyfcm and initialised with this line:

```
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>", proxy_dict=proxy_dict, env='app_engine')
```

It seems that the env='app_engine' part switches all requests to the URLFetch version used on google app engine.